# Elasticsearch outputs the score of 1.0 for all results when searching for a single "starred" term

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using Elasticsearch to search for the most relevant companies in a specific catalog. When we use the normal search term like `lettering` we get reasonable scores and can sort the results according to the score.

However, when we modify the search term before querying and make the "starred" version of it (e.g., `*lettering*`) to be able to search for substrings we get a score of 1.0 for every result. The search for substrings is a requirement in the project.

Any ideas on what could cause this relevance computation? The problem occurs only when a single term is used. We get comprehensible scores when we use two starred terms in combination (e.g., `*lettering* *digital*`).

**EDIT 1**:

Exemplary mapping (YAML, other properties are mapped in the same way, excepting boost which is different for each property):

```
    elasticSearchMapping:
      type: object
      include_in_all: true
      enabled: true
      properties:
        'keywords':
          type: string
          include_in_all: true
          boost: 50
```

Query:

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match_all": []
                }, {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*lettering*"
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "__parentPath": "/sites/industrycatalog"
                    }
                }, {
                    "terms": {
                        "__workspace": ["live"]
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "__dimensionCombinationHash": "d751713988987e9331980363e24189ce"
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "__typeAndSupertypes": "IndustryCatalog:Entry"
                    }
                }],
                "should": [],
                "must_not": [{
                    "term": {
                        "_hidden": true
                    }
                }, {
                    "range": {
                        "_hiddenBeforeDateTime": {
                            "gt": "now"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "range": {
                        "_hiddenAfterDateTime": {
                            "lt": "now"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
},
"fields": ["__path"],
"script_fields": {
    "distance": {
        "script": "doc['coordinates'].distanceInKm(51.75631079999999,14.332867899999997)"
    }
},
"sort": [{
    "customer.featureFlags.industrycatalog": {
        "order": "asc"
    }
}, {
    "_geo_distance": {
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": "51.75631079999999",
            "lon": "14.332867899999997"
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane"
    }
}],
"size": 999999
```

}

Comment: Show your query and mappings.

Comment: Mapping and query added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are doing is `wildcard query`, They fall under `term level queries` and by default `constant score` is applied.

Check the [Lucene Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.html), `WildcardQuery` **extends** `MultiTermQuery`

You can also verify this with the help of [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-explain.html), you will something like this

```
"_explanation": {
     "value": 1,
     "description": "ConstantScore(company:lettering), product of:",
     "details": [{
         "value": 1,
         "description": "boost"
     }, {
         "value": 1,
         "description": "queryNorm"
     }]
 }
```

You can change this behavior with [rewriting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html),

Try this, `rewrite` also works with `query string query`

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "company": {
        "value": "digital*",
        "rewrite": "scoring_boolean"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It has various options for scoring, see what fits your requirement.

**EDIT 1**, the reason you see score other than 1 for `*lettering* *digital*` is due to `queryNorm`, you can again check with `explain api`, If you look closely, all documents with both matches will have **same score** and documents with single match will have same score also.

P.S : **leading wildcard** is not recommended at all. You will get performance issues since it has to check against **every single term** in the `inverted index`. You might want to check [edge ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) or [ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) filter

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, one more question: Is this the correct way to apply `rewrite` to a `query_string` query?

    `{
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "lettering*",
                            "rewrite": "scoring_boolean"
                        }
                    }`